# ToExpression not accepting standard TeX strings

Tags: formatting, latex, input-forms

I am having trouble entering equations in TeX form. I have actually tried a bunch of different equations and gotten similar errors. For example:

```
ToExpression["\\int_0^\\infty e^{-x^2} dx = \\frac{\\sqrt\\pi}2",TeXForm]
```

[image]

Comment: You need to add a thin space before the `dx`: `ToExpression["\\int_0^\\infty e^{-x^2}\\,dx = \\frac{\\sqrt\\pi}2",TeXForm]`.

Comment: @SimonRochester When I do that it returns a "ConditionalExpression", a completely wrong interpretation of the TeX string which should be an integral.

Comment: Mathematica is doing the integral, with the `e` interpreted as an arbitrary variable. Change the `e` to `E` and Mathematica will verify your equation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get your equation in unevaluated form using

```
ToExpression["\\int_0^\\infty E^{-x^2}\\,dx = \\frac{\\sqrt\\pi}2", TeXForm, HoldForm]
```

which wraps the expression in `HoldForm` before evaluation. Note the thin space before `dx`, which is needed for *Mathematica* to properly interpret the integral syntax, and the capital `E`.

```
ToExpression["{HoldForm}[\\int_0^\\infty E^{-x^2}\\,dx = \\frac{\\sqrt\\pi}2]", TeXForm]
```

also works to get the held form.